# Is there a way to see what UDID are included in a build?

Tags: ios, ipa, udid

I am looking for a way to validate an IPA or mobileprovision file, to see if all my test devices have been added before i distribute the app for beta-testing.

Comment: Are you distributing via a service like testflight, or manually?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Open the `.mobileprovision` file in a text editor. The devices included will be listed under the ProvisionedDevices element of the plist section.

If you use testflight, it automatically compares the devices in the profile with your registered testers.

An IPA's contents can be inspected by copying the file, renaming it as `.zip` and unzipping it. Inside there you will find `.mobileprovision` files.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I also unziped the ipa and checked the embedded.mobileprovision.

Comment: The .mobileprovision format is partially in a binary format.  I thought it was a binary plist but it apparently isn't.  What did you use to convert it into a human readable format?

Comment: @MarkWang nothing, just opened it in a text editor. I think the unreadable parts may be some sort of signature or hash. Mind you, I haven't opened one for a long time, so it may look different now.

Comment: Mobileprovision is signed with a certificate, you might need to remove the signature because some junk is added every 1KB or so.

Comment: iPhone Configuration Utility is also good choice. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

Comment: If I have a .ipa file, how do I find the list that relates to that specific build?

Answer (score 4):

I use http://thebetafamily.com/supersend/ to see what UDIDs that are included in my iOS app, also an easy way to send the ipa to my clients.

Comment: How confidential is this service?  If I have a new App that I don't want to disclose to a public service until the App ships as this could be a violation of my NDA with the client.

Comment: @mobibob no one can install/open the app (.ipa) except for those whose UDIDs you signed them with, so there's no risk of NDA violation other than them seeing the name/icon of the app

Answer (score 3):

[Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) Let you to distribute an IPA file and see the provisioned devices on it.

1. Upload IPA file.
2. Open link provided by Diawi after file is uploaded.
3. Click on Companion
4. Click on Provisioned devices
5. See list of UDIDs

Now you IPA file is ready to be distributed and you can be sure who can use it.

[image: Step 2]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Get the iPA/build file. Right click and open with Archive Utility.
> 2. New directory Payload will be created.
> 3. Open the Payload.
> 4. Package file should be there with APP Name.
> 5. Right click on the File, select the “Show Package Contents”.
> 6. Inside this folder, you can file a file named “embedded.mobileprovision”. Open this file using Textedit application.Or Open it using vim editor in terminal.
> 7. Copy your UDID and search among the list of UDIDs in the embedded.mobileprovision file.

[Follow this tutorial:](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-how-to-check-if-an-ipa-file-is-properly-created-for-a-udid-46a44ab7c206)

Comment: The same works if you open .ipa on Windows using, e.g. 7-Zip  `Payload > <my.app> > embedded.mobileprovision`, you can open it with your favorite text editor (Notepad++ in my case) and search for specific UDID

Comment: Thank you for these steps.. its really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

one command:

```sh
zipgrep 00008020-000D15C4343200E2 MyApp.ipa
```

output:

```sh
Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision:Binary file (standard input) matches
```

TL;DR:

- IPA file is a zip file that contains a file `Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision`
  it works on MacOS, I didn't test on other OS

Reference:

- it's based on the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11559771/1489446