# iOS app is still installing into device even after UDID removed from the provisioning profile

Tags: ios

First i added the udid of device and made a build and it got installed in my device . After that i removed the udid from the provision profile and made a new build it again got installed . Without manually deleting provisioning profile from device how to get resolve this issue.Also I don't want remove the device did from apple account.

Comment: Have you installed the new provisioning profile before creating the new build ?

Comment: You need to make sure the updated profile has been installed. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060482/xcode-8-3-xcode-9-0-refresh-provisioning-profile-devices

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here You were removed UDID from your provisional profile that's fine.But

> Did you installed updated new provisional profile with your Keychain by using Xcode.

You can update profile via the option called `Download profiles` through setting ->  preferences by clicking your developer account.

Make sure the changes are done then start to build and try to install your app to some device which is not places in provisional profile.

Comment: I have installed the new provisioning profile but still I am able to install the app. What if the client also have the same problem. the client cannot do all the stuff with Xcode.

Comment: @lavanya no way which type are you exported IPA?ad hoc or development?

Comment: you can check UDID list of your IPA through https://www.diawi.com/.try this to see list of UDID https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020927/3937664

Comment: I am trying to export release Ipa file using development profile